# аналог конструкции "? :" (java) на python-3.x

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, синтаксис

в Java есть такая конструкция:

```java
    rand = Math.random()>0.5 ? "Under" : "Below"
```

позволяющая в одной строке вместить аналог if, есть ли подобные конструкции в Python-3.x?

Comment: это называется тернарный оператор. в гугле в сочетании Python ответов тьма...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например:

```
import random
r = "under" if random.random() > 0.5 else "below"
```

*Я, правда, не совсем понял в каком случае должно быть "below", а в каком "under" (ведь означают они одно и то же), так что результат может оказаться противоположным.*

Comment: Спасибо, то что искал, извиняюсь за "май инглиш из вери гуд" ))

Comment: Всё верно поняли :D "under" в случае истинности выражения, "below" в случае, если оно ложно.